# How to get the other form details using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two forms namely form1 and form2 .

First I submit form1. It goes to the form2 page. Here I need form1 details. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit [help] to see how to ask a question. You will need to add code and explain what you tried. You likely want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045295/re-fill-posted-form-data-via-php-securely

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried $("#load_form").serialize();  but its not working.

Comment: What does that tell us. You need to access the form fields in the php and load them using php

Comment: you can use $_POST on other form2 page for values

Comment: Sorry i have only two html files.

Comment: How you are doing all this stuff, using AJAX or something else, It would be better if you explain this in a little bit details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

the first way with php

form1:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>form1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="form2.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="input1">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

here this form now submit to form2.php:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST)){
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>form2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="input2" value="<?php echo $_POST['input1'];?>">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

so now the value of input in the form1
will be in the input value of form2
and if form1 is not submitted form2 wouldn't appear

the second way with jquery

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
  var input1 = $('#input1').val();
  $("#form1").hide();
  $("#input2").val(input1);
  $("#form2").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='form1' action="form2.php" method="post">
    <div>form1</div>
    <input id='input1' type="text" name="input1">
    <input id='submit' type="button" value="submit">
  </form>

  <form id='form2' action="" method="post" style='display:none'>
    <div>form2</div>
    <input id='input2' type="text" name="input2" value="">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please never name anything in a form `name="submit"` since it will overwrite the submit event handler